# Core dump when catching a warning from topological.sort() of R igraph package

Tags: r, try-catch, warnings, igraph

I tried to use `igraph::topological.sort()` to get topological sort of a graph and check if the graph has cycles. The function only warns and returns partial result when a graph contains cycles, but I have to stop processing when the graph cycles, so I call `igraph::topological.sort()` in `tryCatch()` function.
Then R interpreter was core dumped.

Minimal code to reproduce:

```
library(igraph)

# This has a cycle
adjacency_with_cycle <- matrix(c(0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0), 3, 3)
g_with_cycle <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(adjacency_with_cycle)


# This doesn't
adjacency_without_cycle <- matrix(c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0), 3, 3)
g_without_cycle <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(adjacency_without_cycle)

# Codes below moves
## Only warns on the graph with cycle.

topological.sort(g_with_cycle)
## No problem on the acyclic graph.

topological.sort(g_without_cycle)

## Call in tryCatch. but no warning
tryCatch({
  topological.sort(g_without_cycle)
  },
  warning = function (w) stop())

# Just a tryCatch
tryCatch({warning("warn")}, warning = function (w) stop("stop"))


# Core dumped when catching warning
tryCatch({
  topological.sort(g_with_cycle)
  },
  warning = function (w) stop())    My environments are:
```

My environments are (the problem occurs in both)

- Windwos 10, MRO R 3.3.1, igraph 1.0.1
- Manjaro Linux, R 3.3.2, igraph 1.0.1

Given above, I want to know

- Is this a problem of `igraph` package, or another?
- Why this occurs? What does `tryCatch()` do on catching warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also get an abort and core dump if you use `options(warn=2)` to turn the warning into an error. It is an issue in igraph; you should report it to the igraph maintainer.

Comment: Thank you. I'll report it to the maintainer. I still wonder, in general, how and why catching warnings causes segfault or anything R interpreter can't manage.

Comment: R can't do anything about user C code that misbehaves. Running under `gdb` on Linux and looking at the R code for `topological.sort` tells you that in this case  the `R_igraph_finalizer` C function called from an `on.exit` expression is calling `free` on a bad pointer. Catching an error with `tryCatch` or turning a warning into an error with `options(warn=2)` causes a jump that runs the `on.exit` code. igraph needs to make sure that `R_igraph_finalizer` can be run safely even when such a jump occurs. Over to the igraph maintainer now.

Comment: According to my understand now, does R set the signal handler before the C implemented part is run if it's called within `tryCath()` or `options(warn=2)` is set? So if the signal handler  do something wrong R has nothing to do with it. I've not known how R do things with C, but it became clearer. Thank you for details.